# Mysql Bit(1) column returning 00000000 instead of 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a MySQL table with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_brgpaypal (
        id mediumint(9) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key NOT NULL,
        user_id mediumint NOT NULL,
        month tinyint NOT NULL,
        year tinyint NOT NULL,
        students smallint NOT NULL,
        rating tinyint NOT NULL,
        comission DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
        paid BIT(1) NOT NULL,   
    )
```

But when I insert the value 0 at the paid column it records 00000000. Shouldn't it record just 0?

Comment: What's the difference? Zero is zero no matter how it's presented.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) that isn't the actual table declaration 2) it's fine and the display of the field is not correctly honoring the number of bits. This can be tested by trying to insert `b'10'` - what happens?

Comment: @tadman the result is the same, but I'm thinking about resources. Why use 1 byte to store a 1 bit information. I know that for today standards, this is not really a performance matter, but if you think in big data manipulation where each biyte counts, that can make a difference...

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not in the same machine now, but I'll test bit(10) and update the result here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not necessarily. I think most MySQL storage engines will reserve a full byte of storage for a `BIT(1)`.

The number of bits stored is rounded up to a multiple of 8. A `BIT(1)` occupies the same amount of storage as `BIT(8)`.  (Some storage engines may combine multiple `BIT(n)` columns.)

How did you determine that MySQL " **records `00000000`**"?

What gets returned for a column of `BIT(1)` and how that's displayed is really a client issue, not a database storage issue. Some clients would display it as `b'0'`. But that's not mandated by the MySQL server.

NOTE: If you want to return an integer value of `0` or `1` from the contents of a BIT(1) column, one "trick" is to use an expression to add an integer zero, e.g.

```
  SELECT paid+0 AS paid FROM wp_brgpaypal LIMIT 1
         ^^^^^^
```

But that's not really returning a BIT(1) datatype; that's returning an integer value (as the result of an expression. And this doesn't address what MySQL "records" in a BIT(1) column.

---

On a related note, it's not clear why you are using a `BIT(1)` datatype. Are you intending to represent a boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` value? There are a variety of "mappings" between a logical boolean and database storage.

One of the most common (the one that I always use) is

```
TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'boolean'
```

We take a zero value (`0`) to be FALSE, and any other non-null value to be TRUE. (We store a `1` for TRUE, but the way we decode the column value, any non-null value other than `0` means `TRUE`.

Comment: Storage requirements are true ["_BIT(M) approximately (M+7)/8 bytes_"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html), but I wouldn't know what it would mean for what you get back: `BIT_LENGTH(bitcolumn)` does state 7, but that's officially a string function.

Comment: @Wrikken: I concur. OP said "it records 00000000", and asked "Shouldn't it record just 0?" OP didn't make any reference to what he "gets back". What the client displays is up to the client; it's not a database storage issue. If OP wants to return an integer value of `0` or `1` from `paid BIT(1)`, then OP could return expression `paid+0`. (But that's a different question, how to get a usable value back from a BIT(1) column. That doesn't address what MySQL "records" in a BIT(1) column.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for your answer. I thought it would use just n bits for bit(n), not the nearest byte. I'm really using it for boolean, and that's working fine, but my question was more to understand how does it work. Let's say that I use this to store 1000 rows, I would be using 7000 more bits then I thought. It's not that much if you think in bytes (almost 900), but it's 7 times what I thought  I would need.